# bind Selected item from Collection by combobox and bind it to image

Tags: c#, wpf

How can i bind Selected item from Collection by combobox and bind it to image?

```
public class ElectrodePlacementScheme
{
    public BitmapImage Image { private set; get; }
    public String Name { private set; get; }

    public ElectrodePlacementScheme(BitmapImage image, String name)
    {
        Image = image;
        Name = name;
    }
}
```

User Control: here i init collection by pairs of name and image

```
public partial class CheckECGUC : UserControl
{
    public ObservableCollection<ElectrodePlacementScheme> ElectrodePlacementSchemes { get; set; }

    public CheckECGUC()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        ElectrodePlacementSchemes = new ObservableCollection<ElectrodePlacementScheme>();
        ElectrodePlacementSchemes.Add(new ElectrodePlacementScheme(new BitmapImage(new System.Uri(@"pack://application:,,,/Images/3CH_7Leads_Option1.png")), "Option 1"));
        ElectrodePlacementSchemes.Add(new ElectrodePlacementScheme(new BitmapImage(new System.Uri(@"pack://application:,,,/Images/3CH_7Leads_Option2.png")), "Option 2"));
    }
}
```

xaml: here i try bind image to combobox

```
<ComboBox x:Name="optionSelector" ItemsSource="{Binding ElectrodePlacementSchemes}" DisplayMemberPath="Name"/>
    <Image Source="{Binding Path=optionSelector, ElementName=SelectedItem}"/>
</ComboBox>
```

i see on combobox items: option 1, option 2 but it can not reflected on image: image do not change

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
<ComboBox x:Name="optionSelector" ItemsSource="{Binding ElectrodePlacementSchemes}" DisplayMemberPath="Name"/>
                <Image Source="{Binding SelectedItem.Image, ElementName=optionSelector}">
```

Comment: Well, yes. But this answer needs better formatting.

Answer (score 0):

Or this:

```
    <ComboBox x:Name="optionSelector"
              DisplayMemberPath="Name"
              ItemsSource="{Binding ElectrodePlacementSchemes}"
              SelectedValuePath="Image" />
    <Image Source="{Binding Path=SelectedValue, ElementName=optionSelector}" />
```